# Algorithm for calculating if two routes are "close enough"

Tags: .net, algorithm, wcf

Im sorry if my title is indescriptive.

What I am trying to achieve is a "running app", where I have a pre-defined route to run.

I am logging all the locations the runner is traveling to. When the runner is done; the app send the locations to my WCF service, where I have a route defined in terms of multiple "coordinates" with Latitude and longitude.

what I want to do is to check if the runner did visit all the coordinates "close enough".

A simple loop where I convert all locations to .NET "Geospatial Points" and check the distance from every single user location to the coordinates seems to heavy here.

What i am wondering is if there's an algorithm or best practice in this scenario?

I dont know if such question fits stackoverflow, and if it doesn't; I'm sorry.

Comment: Do you want to know how to calculate if the runner got close enough to to all of the points? Or what should count as close enough?

Comment: I want to know how to calculate it efficiently.

Comment: I don't see how you'll get around checking every single point the user has been at, but you may speed this up considerably if you have an especially large number of points, by indexing them in an R-tree or quad tree.

Comment: Seems too heavy? How many points are you checking? Do you have an actual performance issue or is the premature optimization?

Comment: I'm guessing that the number of points in the predefined route description is fairly small, and the number of points recorded by the app is large, right?  In that case I would suggest building a data structure on the recorded location points that allows fast nearest neighbour queries (for 2D co-ords a good choice is a quadtree). Then iff for each point in the predefined route the nearest neighbour (found from looking up this data structure) is less than `threshold` away, s/he ran the route.

Comment: Since a running route could be anything between 1km and 100km, imagine the number of coordinates representing these long routes. And if multiple users are querying the server with their 100km long runs. I've found this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496/similarity-between-line-strings", but I dont know if it applies to this problem.

Comment: I guess the user locations needs to be checked by sequence aswell, since a route can intersect with itself.

Comment: It makes more sense for you to send the predefined route co-ords *to* the runner's phone, and do the nearest-neighbour testing there.  In fact you could even do this before the run, and then test each location in real time: this might be faster, since you would know that each query is near the last one.

Comment: For the moment I am doing as j_random_hacker did suggest. The question still applies though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want some ideas on how to compare paths with outliers, different sampling frequencies and offsets, check out my thesis work ["The Mean Gaze Path"](http://www.ee.kth.se/php/modules/publications/reports/2007/XR-EE-SB_2007_008.pdf), chapter 5 and 6. The main tools used therein are resampling, longest common substring matching and translation-invariant path representations.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the runner's route is stored as a list of coordinates in increasing order of distance, in which case a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) would help you to locate the closest approach to each checkpoint. Things could get a little more complicated if the runner has to pass the same checkpoint more than once, but you could address that by splitting the route at an intermediate checkpoint between the two visits. (I hope that makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Just saw a cool algorithm called Bouncing Bubble (algorithm at the bottom:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere); that calculates the minimum bounding sphere around a set of points.

You may find this helpful:

1. Pre-calculate the Bouncing Bubble for the pre-defined route on the server.
2. Send the Bubble data to the App. There are only two pieces of data: the center and radius of the bubble.
3. Preform an iteration of the Bouncing Bubble for the dynamic route on the App as the coordinates come in.
4. Compare the radius and center of the Bubbles to determine how close they are. The Bubbles will converge as the route gets closer to completion.

For a more detailed report break the route up into segments and preform the above per segment.